# Facing a bit of challenge while creating a database view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

*Disclaimer: I consider myself a database newbie, and I have just started creating database views myself. I could have probably done some Google searches to find the answer but I didn't even know what the keywords to use - so please bear with me.*

Consider following view script:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.My_First_View
AS
    SELECT 
        mt.*,
        t1.another_id,
        t2.value_i_need
    FROM 
        my_table mt
    LEFT JOIN 
        table_1 t1 ON t1.record_id = mt.record_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        table_2 t2 ON t2.record_id = t1.another_id
GO
```

Just to clarify above script, what I'm ultimately interested in is the value inside the `t2.value_i_need` column. But in order to retrieve that, I need to first pass a value to `table_1` to get some `record_id`, which subsequently gets passed to `table_2` to get the desired value. I hope I'm making sense here.

And, of course, this doesn't seem to work. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Are you getting an error or are you not getting the results you need?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your `CREATE VIEW` statement except that you are performing a `LEFT JOIN` and so `t2.value_i_need` may result in `NULL` if there is no match. You can consider using `COALESCE()` for that like

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.My_First_View
AS
    SELECT mt.*,
    t1.another_id,
    COALESCE(t2.value_i_need, some_default_value)

    FROM my_table mt
    LEFT JOIN table_1 t1
    ON t1.record_id = mt.record_id
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t2.record_id = t1.another_id
GO
```